# Pass arguments to compiler to set defined variables?

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments, argument-passing

It is a possible to pass argument to compiler (command line) and set defined variables:

Example:

```
#define EXVALUE
```

and I want to define EXVALUE at compiling:

```
application.cpp -8
```

'-8' it is a command line argument to define EXVALUE. So I hope that You will understand
what I want, and will help me.

I use Visual Studio C++ 2008 Express Edition.

Thanks. (Sorry for english bads)

Comment: It depends on the compiler, but yes, it's possible.

Comment: Which compiler? With the compiler provided with visual studio it would be something like /D "EXVALUE -8"

Comment: I use Visual Studio C++ 2008 Express Edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio (so also Visual C++ EE) uses `/D` option.

Example:

```
/D "BOOST_ALL_STATIC_LINK"
```

You can do it by GUI : `Project Properties`->`C/C++`->`Preprocessor`->`Preprocessor Definitions`

First link in Google for `visual studio preprocessor definitions` has really nice information, if you need more.